# How to check identical for multiple R objects?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list object such like:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5), y = rbinom(5,2,0.5))
rownames(df) <- LETTERS[1:5]
ls <- list(df1 = df, df2 = df, df3 = df)
```

My question is how to quickly check the row names are identical across the three elements (data frames) in the `ls`.

Comment: just a note, `ls()` refers to a function in base R. Careful using it as an object here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
all(sapply(ls, rownames) == rownames(ls[[1]]))
```

To check only the name of the ith column, you can modify this to

```
all(sapply(ls, rownames)[i, ] == rownames(ls[[1]])[i])
```

Comment: Thanks @konvas. How to just check the rownames or certain column rather than the entire element? That's my question about.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of row names with:

```
Map(rownames, ls)
```

so you can check that all the dataframes have the same rownames checking that there is only one unique value of row.names vector with:

```
length(unique(Map(rownames, ls))) == 1
```